# Resumable upload session uri request with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: upload, google-cloud-storage, resumable

I am trying to generate a resumable session uri using the Google Cloud Storage JSON API. Following the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/resumable-upload) I have put together the following curl command to satisfy only the required arguments

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Length: 1000000" \
-d "uploadType=resumable&name=cat.jpg" \
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o
```

However, this times out and the server never responds.  Note that `Content-Type` is only required if also sending the file metadata.  I've tried also adding the metadata and associated data, but this also fails.

In the example request in the docs there is an `Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN]` header which isn't mentioned in the steps.  I have also tried adding this, using the app's api key, but this also times out.

The ACL on the bucket has been set to all users writable.  CORS is not  configured.

Could anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

The curl verbose output is

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 216.58.208.138...
* Connected to www.googleapis.com (216.58.208.138) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* Server certificate:
*    subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.googleapis.com
*    start date: 2017-10-24 08:38:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2017-12-29 00:00:00 GMT
*    subjectAltName: www.googleapis.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /upload/storage/v1/b/aits-resumables-test/o HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.googleapis.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 1000000
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
> 
* upload completely sent off: 33 out of 33 bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

So I have this working now.  I added the object name in the JSON body and then added the `uploadType=resumable` to the url directly so that it looks like the following

```
curl \
-X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Type: image/jpeg" \
-H "X-Upload-Content-Length: 2000000" \
-d '{"name": "cat.jpg"}' \
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/my-bucket/o?uploadType=resumable
```